# Angle bisector confusion

Tags: geometry

I fooled around with the concept of an angle bisector, and I (thought I) found out (and some websites confirmed this, but now I'm in doubt) that the angle bisector of a vertex is the collection of points equidistant from the 2 sides of the vertex it's bisecting. However, how is this possible. Wouldn't this mean that the bisector would divide the opposite side in 2 equally long segments? But this would create a median, and obviously a median and an angle bisector are different things. Can anyone help?

Comment: "Equidistant from the 2 sides" ... when you measure the distance from a point to a side, you use a line-segment perpendicular to the side.  But your opposite side is probably not perpendicular to the other sides.  So there is no contradiction.

Comment: That's it! Why don't you put this in an answer, so I can give you the best answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**answer copied from comment**

"Equidistant from the 2 sides" ... when you measure the distance from a point to a side, you use a line-segment perpendicular to the side. But your opposite side is probably not perpendicular to the other sides. So there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be to draw a picture. However let me clarify: If you consider a triangle (I guess you considered one), then the angle bisector is indeed the line equidistant from the two sides whose intersection is the vertex. However, **unless the sides are equal,** then it will not bisect the opposite side. To get what I mean, draw a scalene triangle, bisect an angle, measure and convince yourself.

Comment: I am already convinced of that fact sir, however, what concerns me, is that since it doesn't bisect the opposite side, the statement I made doesn't hold, since it is closer to one side than another. Do you understand what I mean? I must stop being equidistant from the sides at one point, thus falsifying the statement.

Comment: I think GEdgar answered your query.